# Calling same Servlet from 2 different clients

Tags: java, swing, servlets

I have to design an Human Machine Interface (HMI) application, which will interact with the devices, like IP Cameras, IP Microphones etc. We are thinking to use Swings as front-end and servlet as back-end. The program will interact with these devices to get the status of the device, like its working or not etc. If it not working then in the UI, the device should start flashing, and its color automatically changes to red. Can anyone let me know how to achieve this with Swings and Servlets?

Can anyone let me know if Servlet is a good to be used for back-end?

Also if I use servlet, then when I open the client program in 2 different machines, will the changes be reflected to both the clients? I mean if I change something, say increase the volume in one client, then the volume must be increased in the other client too. So how do I do that? Is servlet a good option for this?

I really need some help from you guys for building this application.

Comment: Tips: 1) *"Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Dinesh"*  Leave noise out of questions. If your name is important to you, edit [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1302909/user1302909) 2) Add the [tag:java] tag for Java questions! 4) I count 5 questions there.  Please consider to limit it to one specific question per ..question.

Answer (score 1):

From what you defined so far, I'd say that you don't need servlets at all.

You would need some messaging, take a look at JMS brokers:

- http://activemq.apache.org/
- https://mq.java.net/
- http://kafka.apache.org/

and so on. So basicly you will create a topic for some "device" and have number of subscribers for that topic. When device publish something to the topic (like volume increase request) - you will get notified

Comment: @jdevelop.. Thank you so much for your reply. Will this work with Java Swings as front-end?

Comment: yes, it will work as soon as you can connect to the broker from a client host.

Comment: @jdevelop.. Thanks for the reply. I have no idea about the broker, I will need to learn that. It will be really helpful if you can suggest me some good links on this broker and client. Thanks